# can ∃x(x+y=1) be turned into a proposition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My book says all the variables that occur in a propositional function must be bound or set equal to a particular value to turn it into a proposition, and below that there's an example ∃x(x+y=1).
In this example, x is bound and y is free since it's not bounded by a quantifier and no value is assigned to this variable. That's all, no further information is provided in the book.

Even though they're set equal to 1, I'm not sure the statement can be turned into a proposition and have a truth value.

I'm totally new to discrete mathematics.

Comment: What do they mean by "can be turned into a proposition"? Assuming your universe is the set of integers, for example, you could put a $\forall y$ at the beginning and this would then be a proposition.  What happens if your universe is the set of positive integers? Is $\exists y\exists x(x+y=1)$ a proposition? Is it true or false?

Comment: It's also a proposition and false, is that right sir?